# Passing Odata Query Options in the Request Body

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

In the [Odata 4.01 URL conventions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_PassingQueryOptionsintheRequestBody) it says that for `GET` requests with extremely long filter expressions you can append `/$query` to the resource path of the URL, use the `POST` verb instead of `GET`, and pass the query options part of the URL in the request body. If I try that with my service I get back a 404.

Does the `/$query` endpoint need to be manually created in the back end or is this something odata is supposed to take care of transparently? I've been searching like crazy but I'm having trouble finding anything about how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

To support this you add `app.UseODataQueryRequest()` to your startup **somewhere *before*** `app.UseRouting()`

The framework then transforms ~/$query POST requests into GET requests which are handled by the `HttpGet` action methods on your controller ([source](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2414#issuecomment-780052614)).

- Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/query-options-in-request-body) (although currently not up to date)
- For a complete sample have a look [here](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/main/sample/ODataRoutingSample)

Answer (score 0):

> One way to avoid this is wrapping the request in a batch request

You can resolve long url with $batch query.

Good post from Hassan Habib https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/all-in-one-with-odata-batch//

All what you should do is:

1. **Allow batching in Startup.cs**

   ```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {  
            app.UseODataBatching(); <---- (1)
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.Select().Filter().Expand().OrderBy();
                endpoints.MapODataRoute(
                    routeName: "api",
                    routePrefix: "api",
                    model: GetEdmModel(),
                    batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler()); <---- (2)
            });
        }
   ```
2. **Request batch query with body, that contains long url request**

POST http://localhost/api/$batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_mybatch

body:

```
--batch_mybatch
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET http://localhost/api/students/735b6ae6-485e-4ad8-a993-36227ac82851  HTTP/1.1   <--long url requst
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services

--batch_mybatch
```